# How can I open up lock screen settings page in my app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I've made a hyperlink and implemented the click event, but how can I make it so that it opens up the lock screen settings page for my phone?

I want to shortcut it for my users so they can set up notifications

Answer (score 3):

You can't open the lock screens settings from your code in WP7.

I know you've tagged it `windows-phone7` but here's how you can do it in WP8 for those who come across this question and are targetting WP8. Simply use the [LaunchUriAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh701484.aspx) method

```
var openedLock = await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-lock:"));
```

`ms-settings-lock` is the lock screen settings URI but you can see the other available URI schemes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: I can't open up lockscreen setting for windows phone 7.8? Thats kinda sad